# JQuery get Class issue

Tags: jquery, attr

I have an issue in JQuery in getting **CLASS NAME** of **clicked element**.

Here's my code so far: [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/Unknownymous/pen/BwFfL?editors=001)

**HTML**

```
<div class="sideNav">
    <a href="#" id="technical" class="servicesTech">
        <div class="sideThumb cap-left">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/technics" />
            <figcaption class="thumb_caption">Sample1</figcaption>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="sales" class="servicesSales">
        <div class="sideThumb cap-left">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/business" />
            <figcaption class="thumb_caption">Sample2</figcaption>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){           

    $('a').bind('click', function(){
        idName = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
        className= $(this).attr('id');
        var getClassElem = $(this).attr('class');

        alert(getClassElem);

        $("a").removeClass();
        $(idName).addClass(className);
    });

});
```

**Issue**

It only works on first load of the page. but when I clicked the other MENU it doesn't show on ALERT. I just used ALERT for showing if it is retrieving correctlt.

Any help will so much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: No code in the CodePen. Sorry!

Comment: How come? please try again..

Comment: No pens here! It says, "There is nothing here, Monsieur. My giant magnifying glass on a stick tells no lies."

Comment: CodePen, JSFiddle, JSBin is not a substitute. You should always post relevant code here. __As CodePen is not available, Question is good candidate for close vote.__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written:

```
$('a').bind('click', function(){
    idName = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
    className= $(this).attr('id');
    var getClassElem = $(this).attr('class');

    alert(getClassElem);

    $("a").removeClass();
    $(idName).addClass(className);
});
```

It can be optimized as:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $("a").removeAttr("class");
    $(this).addClass($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Few other things:

1. What are you trying to do?
2. How can you have a `<div>` element inside an `<a>` element?

Comment: thank you for that optimization.

1. what I'm trying to do is just get the `class name` of that clicked `LINK` then that `CLASS NAME` will open new main content.

2. Actually, I google it then I found this:[HERE!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct). Thanks for that info. I will update my HTML. Therefore its not working because of that `<div>` element inside an `<a>` element?

Comment: Yes. Many browsers will kick out `<div>` elements inside `<a>` elements!

Comment: Ok thank you so much sir. So you mean my retrieving of class in JQUERY is correct is just that my HTML is wrong?

Comment: To an extent, yes! :)